# How do I convert this into peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I have this SQLquery, and I'm currently executing it in peewee like so

```
sql = "select DATE(inserted) Date, COUNT(*) totalCount FROM tbl_rss_region GROUP BY DATE(inserted)"

db.execute_sql(sql)
```

Would it be possible to write this off as as a db.select(DATE(tbl_rss_region.inserted)....) statement?

I have tried this, but it's not grouping them by date, and also taking into consideration the time, so it's getting me the wrong values:

```
for l in TBL_RSS_REGION.select(TBL_RSS_REGION.inserted, fn.COUNT(TBL_RSS_REGION.id).alias("count")).group_by(TBL_RSS_REGION.inserted):
    print l.inserted, l.count

2015-08-31 09:31:33.530000 1
2015-08-31 09:31:33.538000 1
2015-08-31 09:31:33.549000 1
2015-08-31 09:31:33.561000 1
2015-08-31 09:31:33.569000 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to write:

```
TRS = TBL_RSS_REGION  # ew all caps, wtf bro
query = (TRS
         .select(
             fn.DATE(TRS.inserted).alias('day'),
             fn.COUNT(TRS.id).alias('count'))
         .group_by(fn.DATE(TRS.inserted)))
```

You used `fn.COUNT`, perhaps you didn't know you could use it with any arbitrary SQL function?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to truncate.

```
TBL_RSS_REGION.select(db.truncate_date("day", TBL_RSS_REGION.inserted), fn.COUNT(TBL_RSS_REGION.id).alias("count")).group_by(
            db.truncate_date("day", TBL_RSS_REGION.inserted))
```